# jQuery carousel positioning issues

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to do something rather simple, but having a few problems. I want to use BX-Slider ([www.bxslider.com](http://www.bxslider.com)) in carousel mode. I can get it installed and working but the CSS positioning of the slider is really not right. You can see in my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/a59ne/1/) (with plugin attached), the thumbnails go waaaaaay off the screen and they're supposed to be in the grey box! I would really appreciate some advice on how to rectify this problem.

This is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // start article gallery slider
    var main_gallery_slider = $('#main_gallery_slider').bxSlider({
        auto: true,
        controls: false,
        displaySlideQty: 4
    });

});
```

And here is my HTML/slider:

```
<div class="main_gallery" style="width:600px; background:#333; padding:10px;">
    <ul id="main_gallery_slider" style="width:600px;">
        <li><img src="myImage.jpg" width="90" height="60" /></li>
        <li><img src="myImage.jpg" width="90" height="60" /></li>
        <li><img src="myImage.jpg" width="90" height="60" /></li>
        <li><img src="myImage.jpg" width="90" height="60" /></li>
        <li><img src="myImage.jpg" width="90" height="60" /></li>
        <li><img src="myImage.jpg" width="90" height="60" /></li>
        <li><img src="myImage.jpg" width="90" height="60" /></li>
        <li><img src="myImage.jpg" width="90" height="60" /></li>
        <li><img src="myImage.jpg" width="90" height="60" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

There is no CSS to go with this apart from the little bits which I added inline and here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a59ne/1/) (http://jsfiddle.net/a59ne/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `li` tags are having a width applied to them, if you set the width in the css.

```
#main_gallery_slider li { width: 90px; }
```

That would solve it assuming you want them all the same width.

Comment: Thanks. Bit silly really. I assumed that as BXSlider didn't provide any CSS examples in their documentation/installation notes, that the JS script automatically styles and positions the sliding elements.